# Установка Silverlight 5 Developer

Tags: установка, silverlight

Никак не могу установить Silverlight 5 SDK. Требования к установке не ясны, ставил уже 5 раз то одно, то другое, плюс он еще только вышел. Появился Dev Tools на русском но проблема осталась. При установке пишет "нужно установить ....", но это не помогает! Помогите, пожалуйста, кто уже его ставил, а то хочется попробовать там 3D.

Comment: Ставил не один раз - проблем не было. Единственно требуется на сколько я помню, чтобы VS была с сервис паком (без него инстал не запускается).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему установкой VS2012